# PHP $_GET should return array instead of string

Tags: php

I have a strange error with a $_GET Value. I'm using this code for a query:
`array($_GET['cats'])`

If I insert the get parameter manually, like: `array(3,328)` everything works fine. But if I use:
`array($_GET['cats'])` and submit the cats by URL like `?cats=3,328` it does not work. What could be the issue?

Comment: make sure you can differentiate when something is an error, and when it is just showing behavior that you don't expect...in this case, as the 5 answers below show, what you are seeing is not an error, you are just expecting different results.  reading the docs can be a good way to check this.

Answer (score 4):

You can't plug a value like that. `array($_GET['cats'])` is equivalent to `array('3,328')`, if the value of `$_GET['cats']` is `3,328`. So basically, the value is a string, not a list of integers. What you want is:

```
explode(',', $_GET['cats'])
```

Answer (score 4):

`array($_GET['cats'])` will create an array containing the single element that’s value is the value of `$_GET['cats']`, no matter what value it is. In case of the string value `3,328` is would be identical to `array('3,328')`.

If you want to turn the string value `3,328` into an array identical to `array(3,328)`, use [`explode`](http://php.net/explode) to split the string at `,` into strings and [`array_map`](http://php.net/array_map) with [`intval`](http://php.net/intval) to turn each string into an integer:

```
$arr = array_map('intval', explode(',', $_GET['cats']));
```

Now this resulting array is really identical to `array(3,328)`:

```
var_dump($arr === array(3,328));  // bool(true)
```

Comment: If it do it in your way, I get `bool(true)` but the query still does not work. This is my full code:

Comment: '$query_new = array_map('intval', explode(',', $_GET['cats']));
var_dump($query_new  === array(3,328));

$args = array(
   'category__and' => array($query_new),
);'

Comment: The result ist still different to that one, where I set `3,328` manually

Comment: @Cindy: In your case `$query_new` already is the array in the form you want it. Doing `var_dump($query_new === array(3,328));` is the proof that `$query_new` identical to `array(3,328)` (that what you wanted).

Comment: Yep. But the results are still different to those I get, if I insert `3,328` manuallay.

Comment: `$args = array( 'category__and' => array($query_new), );` != `$args = array( 'category__and' => array(3,328), );` but `$args = array( 'category__and' => $query_new, );` == `$args = array( 'category__and' => array(3,328), );` if i guess it right

Comment: @Cindy: Every parameter passed via GET is a string. So `?cats=3,328` will result in something that is identical to doing `$_GET['cats'] = '3,328';`. And if you take that variable and do `array($_GET['cats'])`, then that is identical to just taking the value of `$_GET['cats']`, that is `'3,328'`, and doing `array('3,328')`. That is an array with one element that’s value is the string value `'3,328'`. It is *not* the same as `array(3,328)` that is an array with the integer value `3` and `328`. So what exactly do you want?

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, $_GET['cats'] is a string as you're doing things at the moment.

However, if you change your URI querystring to `?cats[]=3,328` then `$_GET['cats']` will be the `array(3,328)` ready for you to use.

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution 1: Send HTTP GET parameters as an array in your URL

**URL: parameters** ?cats[]=3&cats[]=328

`var_dump($_GET["cats"])` will result in:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "3"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "328"
}
```

#### Solution 2: Send numbers as one string in URL and process it with PHP

**URL parameters:** ?cats=3,328

... and then process it with some PHP code:

```
$cats = array_map("intval", explode(",", $_GET["cats"]));
```

`var_dump($_GET["cats"])` will result in:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "3"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "328"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$_GET['cats']` is a simple string. If you want to get 3 and 328 as seperate values you need to use `explode`. You can than use `foreach` to print your exploded values.

Answer (score 0):

You need to split up the GET-Parameters

```
$values = explode(',', $_GET['cats'])
```